# Malware on Mac OS Big Sur and/or Catalina

Tags: malware, virus

So I was wondering if I were to be infected with malware would it be visible? For example most malware will want to gain access to system files.

Since Catalina Apple introduced some insight into Security/Privacy via settings inside System preferences, which lists applications that have and/or have requested access to Camera, Microphone, Full Disk access etc.

So my question is if I were to be infected with malware that wanted access to my camera and/or system files etc, would it be listed as application that has requested access and/or has access already inside system preferences > security & privacy settings.

Comment: That depends entirely on the malware in question and is unanswerable.

Comment: @MechMK1 do you mean in terms of whether the malware is using exploits to avoid permission or is there other routes malware will take to gain access to files/folders rather than go through apples default route similar to legitimate apps?

Comment: Both is possible. While I don't know any current exploits, it can never be ruled out that malware can circumvent such security controls.